# not able to delete file from command line in windows server 2008

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch program in windows server 2008
I am using robocopy command and /move parameter to copy and delete the file from source path. Not able to succeed.

Then I tried using DEL dos command.  Not successful. 
Throwing access error

Could you please let me know the dos command to forcefully delete a file or clear the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the file is write-protected, try:

```
del /f file
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have permission to that file/folder.  Even if you are an admin... open an administrative Command Prompt by Right Clicking on CMD.exe or shortcut and 'Run as administrator'.
AN administrator does not have the same privileges as THE local Administrator.